# AWS Elasticsearch exceeded limit of total fields in index

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, index-error

I'm running `Elasticsearch` on `AWS`, and haven't quite understood how to properly address this issue.

Right now I have the items stored on `DynamoDb` and use `dynamodb streams` to send the items to a lambda that then uses [dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch) to send them to elasticsearch when they are created/updated.

Some properties can be objects which have many nested properties which can themselves be objects, and when these new fields were added, is when I first started getting this error. Due to the nature of these items, these new properties will need to be searchable in the future.

Initially the default index value had not been changed. After my first search on how to fix this I increased the limit to 5000 and now have had to increase it to 12000. The instance type is a t2.small.elasticsearch. The aws elasticsearch console is already reporting the instance health as yellow after I increased the index limit.

Which is the best way to tackle this sort of situation?

Does increasing the instance type fix it or is it a matter of breaking up the item and having multiple separate indexes? If the solution is the latter, is there a good tutorial/guide on how to do this with this set-up (aws dynamodb/elasticsearch)?

Comment: Are you running a single-node instance? In my experience, single-node reports yellow because the default index template creates a replica (that then can't be assigned on a single node). Go to `https://ENDPOINT/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason` in your browser (replacing `ENDPOINT` with your actual endpoint) and see if there are unassigned shards.

Comment: Re your initial problem, I don't think that simply increasing the fields limit will help you, because it sounds like your Dynamo table keeps adding fields. Instead, think about what you want to index and why; it's likely that you can pick out a few "important" fields, and then just store the rest of the document as a big text field for free-form search.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the maximum number of fields in an index is **1000**, But you can increase that by changing the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` index setting.

**See other settings to prevent mappings explosion:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings

Which is the best way to tackle this sort of situation?

*This could be a solution if you use **flattened***

> The **nested** type is a specialised version of the object datatype that
>   allows arrays of objects to be indexed in a way that they can be
>   queried independently of each other.
>
> When ingesting key-value pairs with a large, arbitrary set of keys,
>   you might consider modeling each key-value pair as its own nested
>   document with key and value fields. Instead, consider using the
>   **flattened** datatype, which maps an entire object as a single field and
>   allows for simple searches over its contents. Nested documents and
>   queries are typically expensive, so using the flattened datatype for
>   this use case is a better option.

Comment: Will this error continue to manifest itself regardless of the instance size set on aws?

Comment: I used `r5.xlarge.elasticsearch` for data and `r5.large.elasticsearch` for my master node on AWS ES but I guess this field issue is regardless of instance size.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it would be.